# Include the drop-down value into a SQL query in ColdFusion

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I have a page that shows a list of students. I want to use a dropdown to implement a filter. When option 1 (high school students) is selected shows only high school students, when option 2 is selected (college students) is selected shows only college students and so on.
The query will be:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, age 
FROM students 
WHERE studentCategory = #dropDownValue#
```

Is there any way to do this without using javascript nor any submit button. I am trying to pass the dropdown value to the URL but I am not sure how to change the URL when an option is selected from dropdown. 
I appreciate any help.

Comment: You will need to either use Ajax or a form submit. There are literally thousands of tutorials.

Comment: I think there is a way to send the value of the selected option to the URL and then check using something like <cfif isDefined("URL.value") and URL.value EQ "someValue"> update query </cfif>
The problem is that I am not sure how to send the value of the selected option to the URL.

Comment: Use a form submit instead of url

Comment: *not sure how to change the URL when an option is selected* Unless there is something more to it, you do not need to change the URL yourself. A [`<form method="GET" ...>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4) does that already. It automatically appends successful form fields to the "action" URL. Try it out by creating a simple form with just a <select> list and a submit button. BTW, what is this question tagged CSV?

Comment: Darn 5 min edit limitation ... that last line should be "why" is this question tagged CSV?

Comment: I tagged Ajax and ColdFusion. I am not sure what do you mean by CSV.

Comment: And don't use isDefined("URL.xxxxxx"). Use structKeyExists(url,"xxxxxx") instead. It's a bit less along the same path as ParameterExists(). :-)

Comment: One way to do this without a submit button is to put the dropdown into a form and use the onBlur event of the dropdown to submit the form.  Be aware though, that you are not giving the user a chance to think his choice over because there is no explicit form submission.

Comment: @DoArNa - No, it was originally tagged CSV. Looks like James [modified the tags in a edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43242583/revisions)

Comment: Something else to remember, especially if you use variables from a form directly on a query, is to use the `<cfqueryparam>` function. This is important to protect your application from SQL Injection. [Here](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/677.cfm) is a good article on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you add onChange to the first SELECT.

```
<select 
name="doesntmatter"
onChange="document.location.href='?studentCategory='+this.value;">
```

However consider using ajax as it will be much faster.